# Italicizing labels using ordipointlabel function in vegan package

Tags: r, vegan

I'm trying to figure out how to produce italicized labels using the `ordipointlabel()` function from the vegan package in R. My points represent species so I'd like the scientific names to be in italics. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Example code:

```
ordipointlabel(sp.mds, display="species", col = "black", pch=25, cex=1)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I've answered my own question. It's stupidly simple. Add "font=3" to plot code.


ordipointlabel(sp.mds, display="species", col = "black", pch=25, cex=1, font=3)

Comment: Consider adding this as a proper Answer so it can be voted on and accepted by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "font=3" to plot code.

ordipointlabel(sp.mds, display="species", [col](http://inside-r.org/r-doc/base/col) = "black", pch=25, cex=1, font=3)